# Ng Module watch in angular 6 not updates the html page

Tags: angular, sharepoint-online, p-np

Actually I am working alongside without SharePoint with Pnp Js Rest Api . I am hosting the bundled files on SharePoint itself.. When i do ng build --watch its observing the changes but isn't reflected on the html files after build..

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```
ng build --watch=true
```

or

```
ng b --watch=true
```

The default is `false`

Comment: Its not working. It serves the previous html file that was created at the start of the project. The ng build --watch= true also does the same as ng build --watch. No changes seen so far.

Comment: @suriyaprakash try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54816109/angular-7-library-html-template-changes-are-not-affected-into-application-when-c and can you also post your angular.json ?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/suryarsp/SnacksPicker/master/angular.json?token=AFALO5KACI236VGACNVL63C42HB4S @dota2pro

Comment: @suriyaprakash the link you posted gives me a  404 error

Answer (score 0):

My **angular.json** file @dota2pro

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Office365Test": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "Office",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "spec": false
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/Office365Test",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/styles/styles.css",
              "src/assets/styles/app.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Office365Test:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Office365Test:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Office365Test:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Office365Test-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Office365Test:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "Office365Test:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Office365Test"
}
```